# Python script to zoom to a city and export as PDF won't zoom to city

Tags: arcpy, cursor, zoom

The script completes successfully but doesn't zoom to the given city. It does export to PDF with the correct name though. The map is the county wide extent and not zoomed to the given city. The print cityName statement does return the correct city that is entered by the user. Any ideas?

```
# imports and environment setup
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as MAP     # alias for the module name
import time                     # module that allows you to time your script

rootFolder = r'\\myFilePath'
arcpy.env.workspace = r'myWorkspace'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# open the MXD and set varibles for the dataframe, working layers, title
mxd = MAP.MapDocument(r'{}\ZoomToCity.mxd'.format(rootFolder))

dataframe = MAP.ListDataFrames(mxd, 'Focus City')[0]

selectedCityLyr = MAP.ListLayers(mxd, 'SelectedCity', dataframe)[0]


titleTextElm = MAP.ListLayoutElements(mxd, 'TEXT_ELEMENT', 'SelectedCity')


## user inputs a city name
input = raw_input('Enter a City (e.g., CITY A -- case sensitive): ')



### create a search cursor to select the desired city from the "City" FC

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('city_limits', 'CITY_NAME', "CITY_NAME = '{}'".format(input)):
                ## get the city name from the cursor list
                cityName = row[0]

                print cityName

                # update the map title
                titleTextElm = '{}'.format(cityName)

                ## set definition query to the selected city layer -- provides special symbology
                selectedCityLyr.definitionQuery = "CITY_NAME = '{}'".format(cityName)

                ## use the SelectLayerByAttribute tool to select the city
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(selectedCityLyr, 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                                "CITY_NAME = '{}' ".format(cityName) )
                ## zoom to the selected city
                dataframe.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

                ## clear the selection to remove the city selection symbology from the map
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(selectedCityLyr,'CLEAR_SELECTION')


                ## Export the map as a PDF image file named for the selected city
                MAP.ExportToPDF(mxd, r'{}\activeMaps\{}.pdf'.format(rootFolder, cityName))

                 ## print a message for each city map image created
                print 'Completed map of: "{}"'.format(cityName)



# clear the selection and refresh the active view
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(selectedCityLyr, 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

# clear the connection to the map document
del mxd
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your code so that it has a legal indentation scheme.

Comment: Try to print `cityName` after your `cityName = row[0]` to make sure you have non-None row object.

Comment: I think you should decide whether to focus this particular question on either how to update the Title or how to zoom to the given city, and then reduce the code snippet presented to focus on that.

Comment: Your performance timing code while useful in your full script seems unrelated to the issues you are trying to resolve so I think that should be removed to simplify the code snippet that you present.

Comment: I edited my post. Does it pass now?